# Does CloudKit "aggregate" update change notifications?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

If client make changes on the same record several time, do subscribers get several notifications, or only one? Is it possible to get only one? If app was launched for long time, then this can be a significant reduction of network usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you cannot assume that all notifications arrive in the application didReceiveRemoteNotification

when an application didReceiveRemoteNotification is called, you should also execute a CKQueryNotification to see if there are more notifications that needs to be processed.

what notifications do arrive in application didReceiveRemoteNotification depend on the total load on icloud and the number of notifications that are send within some time limit.